# Python Unit test with i18 but without webapp2

Tags: python, unit-testing, google-app-engine, webapp2, python-babel

I encountered a problem with unit tests when use i18 in my project.
My project uses framewoks i18 and webapp2
The function uses the translation by i18. But when I test, I get the error - missing global variable request.
For example it is:

```
from unittest import TestCase, main
from webapp2_extras.i18n import lazy_gettext as _

def Hello(a):
    if a > 0:
       message = _('My great message!11 a > 0')
    else:
       message = _('My great message!11 a =< 0')
    return message

class TestHandler(TestCase):

    def testHello0(self):
        self.assertEqual(Hello(0), 'My great message!11 a =< 0')

    def testHello3(self):
        self.assertEqual(Hello(3), 'My great message!11 a > 0')

if __name__ == '__main__':
     main()
```

and I have message:

```
FAIL: testHello0 (text3.TestHandler)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/text3.py", line 14, in testHello0
    self.assertEqual(Hello(0), 'My great message!11 a =< 0')
AssertionError: Request global variable is not set.
```

I have a solution to this problem, but I do not like it. This is a crutch. How can you test my function without using framewoks on similarity webapp2

```
from unittest import TestCase, main
from webapp2_extras.i18n import lazy_gettext as _
import webapp2

def Hello(a):
    if a > 0:
        message = _('My great message!11 a > 0')
    else:
        message = _('My great message!11 a =< 0')
    return message


class OneHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        myNumber = self.request.get('myNumber')
        myNumber = int(myNumber)
        message = Hello(myNumber)
        self.response.write(message)


routes = [('/One', OneHandler)]
app = webapp2.WSGIApplication(routes = routes)

class TestHandler(TestCase):

    def testHello0(self):
        myNumber = 0
        URL = '/One?myNumber=%s' % myNumber

        self.response = app.get_response(URL)
        self.mess = self.response.body
        self.assertEqual(self.mess, 'My great message!11 a =< 0') 

    def testHello3(self):
        myNumber = 3
        URL = '/One?myNumber=%s' % myNumber

        self.response = app.get_response(URL)
        self.mess = self.response.body
        self.assertEqual(self.mess, 'My great message!11 a > 0') 


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

and well done!

```
Ran 2 tests in 0.047s

OK
```

But it's not a good solution. How I can testing my function and dont use webapp2, etc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just don't test external code and patch your _lazy function

```py
from unittest import TestCase
import fudge

from path.to import fun
# def fun(msg):
#     return _lazy("foo %s") % msg

class TestHandler(TestCase):
    @fudge.patch("path.to._lazy")
    def test_foo(self, fake_lazy)
        fake_lazy.is_callable().calls(lambda s, **kw: s)
        self.assertEqual(fun("bar"), "foo bar")
```

Answer (score 0):

I removed my function Hello() in the file TEXT31.py.
and after that I used next code:

```
from unittest import TestCase, main
import TEXT31

def dummy_gettext(message):
    return message

TEXT31._ = dummy_gettext # original _-function requires webapp2 environment

class TestHandler(TestCase):

    def testHello0(self):
        self.assertEqual(TEXT31.Hello(0), 'My great message!11 a =< 0')

    def testHello3(self):
        self.assertEqual(TEXT31.Hello(3), 'My great message!11 a > 0')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

WEll done!
I relax...